# Ожидание загрузки страницы selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, браузер

Нужно написать такой код:
если страница не загрузилась, то продлить время ожидания на 5 секунд. И так делать до момента загрузки страницы.

ps пробовал через browser.current_url, но не получилось. Помогите, пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 0):

```
def wait(xpath) -> bool:
    """
    Метод для ожидания загрузки элемента на странице
    также можно использовать указав любой тег
    в кодировке xpath к примеру wait('//a')
    таким образом браузер будет ждать появление тегов <a>

    :param xpath: xpath элемента для ожидания
    :return bool: True
    """
    for _ in range(60):
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        if elements is not []:
            return True
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```